# How to unregister Auslogic BoostSpeed

Tags: windows, license

Is there a way to unregister Auslogic Boostspeed 5?  I want to move my copy to another computer.

Comment: Uninstall? or do you want something like removing the reg keys manually?

Comment: Uninstalling doesent seem to quite do it. When I reinstalled the program(long story) it automagically registered itself. I need it to now register under a different key.

Comment: See if [revo unistaller](http://download.cnet.com/Revo-Uninstaller/3000-2096_4-10687648.html) can find the keys.

Answer (score 0):

All Auslogics programs licenses (except Auslogics Antivirus) can be used on up to 3 computers within one household. It means, for example, that you can use one license of Auslogics BoostSpeed on up to 3 computers if they belong to you. However, you cannot give the license to someone else. If the program is to be used by several people, you can purchase two or more licenses at a discounted price.